# d3.js time series bar chart best practice?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I love both `d3.scaleBand().bandwidth()` and `d3.axisBottom(scaleTime())`.

Can I have the best of both worlds?

More concretely: I have a time series bar chart whose aggregation level is changeable but the outermost bars extend beyond my range at the highest date aggregation. This is because I used `d3.scaleTime()` for setting up my horizontal positions, as the axis tick generation is just lovely.
[Observable notebook](https://beta.observablehq.com/@korompaiistvan/bar-chart-object-constancy#generateChart)

What’s the best practice here, as I see three options:

1. Use `d3.scaleTime()` with custom bandwidth calculation, and play
       with the range before I generate the axis, so everything lines up
       properly
2. Use `d3.scaleBand()` and take care of the tick formatting somehow
   (eww)
3. Use both, `d3.scaleBand()` for the actual positioning and
   `d3.scaleTime()` for the axis generation (seems stinky)

Oddly enough I couldn’t find a good example of how this was done elsewhere.

Comment: The issue here is quite simple: you should **not** use a bar chart for a time series. Any solution you come up with here will be a bit hacky. Please, have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48278994/5768908

Comment: Also, in this particular case, any answer will be opinion-based and, therefore, the question itself is off topic. I reckon that the only "non opinion-based" answer would be: *"don't use a bar chart for a time series"*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You're conflating two separate things in your answer: dataviz best practices and d3.js limitations. 
If I understand your point currently, you're saying that because bar charts categorically *shouldn't* be used in a time series representation, the functionality I'm looking for is not available in d3.js.

I would like to ask you to point out or offer a more elaborate explanation of your "non-opinion-based" argument.

I'm also aware that I'm only going to receive opinion-based answers to this question; it is to be expected with best practice questions.

Comment: No, the functionality you're looking for doesn't exist, you'll have to hack either the bars or the axis. Regarding the question, there are certainly "best practices" questions which are not opinion based. This one, however, is opinion based because the answers (the opinions) will favour one hack or another. As I said, the best practice here is, undoubtedly, not using a bar chart.