# How can I apply a time scale and show my data in intervals of "n" years?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need use a time scale for the x axis to represent the year. It may
be necessary to use time parsing/formatting when you load and display
the year data. The axis would be overcrowded if you display every year
value so I'd like to set the x-axis ticks to display one tick for every 3 years.

how can do it?

[image]

this is my live code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qOqvG5T0yb0P4TbW6Kv6?p=preview

```
d3.dsv(",", "data.csv").then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);


  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.running_total; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.year); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.running_total); })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.running_total); });

  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides changing the scale...

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
```

... and the domain...

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.year; }));
```

... the important part here is using [`interval.every`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_every) to set the interval between the ticks.

For instance, one tick every 10 years:

```
d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(10))
```

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aSHJ6cIZyb0h1st1mX5w?p=preview

---

PS: you should **not** use bars (bar chart) with time as a variable. That's not the purpose of a bar chart. For instance, you'll have the problem of the bar width (which in the Plunker I set to 10 pixels). Have a look at my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279536/5768908

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today. I know it is not part of the question, but I take advantage of your kindness and great knowledge. Do you know why there is a space between the y-axis and the bars ( https://i.imgur.com/dSHQurg.jpg) ? and I also want to know if you know any way to remove the comma (,) on the y axis. thanks genius!

Comment: @yavg you have to coerce the strings to numbers. Regarding the ticks, use `tickFormat`. Here are the changes: https://plnkr.co/edit/mRjyYN9nWiMWYRzj7Gtf?p=preview