# d3.js Why are axis and data slightly offset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’m building a bar chart with d3.js, and for some reason my x axis is ever so slightly misaligned with my bars. I’ve combed through my code and can’t seem to figure out why. I’m sure it’s something simple, but I just can’t put my finger on it. Any chance I could get another pair of eyes to see what I’ve missed?
The JavaScript:

```
let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

// function fired when state is selected
document.getElementById("state-select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
//   if there's already a chart, remove it
  let chart = document.getElementById("chart");
  if (chart) {
    chart.remove();
  };
  let state = e.target.value;
//   get state data
  fetch(`https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/${state}/daily.json`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
//     sort data by date, chop off initial null value
      data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
      data = data.slice(1);
//     turn data date strings into date objects
      data.forEach(item => {
        if (item.positiveIncrease < 0){
          item.positiveIncrease = 0
        }
        let dateObject = new Date(item.dateChecked);
        let year = dateObject.getFullYear();
        let month = dateObject.getMonth();
        let day = dateObject.getDate();
        item.dateChecked = new Date(year, month, day);
      });


//     set variables for dimensions and spacing
      const svgWidth = window.innerWidth * .8;
      const svgHeight = window.innerHeight * .8;
      const padding = 40;
      const chartWidth = svgWidth - padding * 2;
      const chartHeight = svgHeight - padding * 2;
      const barSpace = 3;
      const barWidth = chartWidth / data.length - barSpace;

//    build y scale
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear();
      yScale.domain([
        d3.min(data, (d) => d.positiveIncrease),
        d3.max(data, (d) => d.positiveIncrease),
      ]);
      yScale.range([chartHeight, 0]);

//     build y axis
      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

//     build x scale
      const xScale = d3.scaleTime();
      xScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.dateChecked), d3.max(data, d => d.dateChecked)]);
      xScale.range([0, chartWidth]);

//     build x axis
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);

//     add svg to svg wrapper
      const svg = d3
        .select("#svg-wrapper")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .attr('id', 'chart');

//      add axes
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, ${padding})`).call(yAxis);
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, ${chartHeight + padding })`).call(xAxis);

//     add bars
      let rect = svg
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", (d) => yScale(0) - yScale(d.positiveIncrease))
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (barWidth + barSpace) + padding)
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.positiveIncrease) + padding);

//     add title to rects
      rect.append("title").text((d) => {return `${d.positiveIncrease}, ${months[d.dateChecked.getMonth()]} ${d.dateChecked.getDate()}`});

//     add header
      svg
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text(state + " New Cases Daily")
        .style("font-size", "1.5rem")
        .style("font-weight", "bold");
    });
});
```

And [here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/LuosRestil/pen/MWaoyRr) of the project.

Comment: Your x scale is a continuous scale, on it elements don't have a width. The y axis marks the first date and the last point on the x axis marks the end date. But, you're dividing the width of the axis by how many entries there are. For the last bar, for example, the last date's rectangle is placed at `chartWidth - barWidth`, while the scale treats `chartWidth` as where the last date should be placed. By using two different methods to position rect and tick there is a misalignment. I'll look for some good answers to this issue.

Comment: I'd take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279536/7106086), I had another example somewhere but have misplaced it, but the solution was not drastically different.

Comment: your x position is determined by index, not by scaling. This won't fix it all, but it's a start: .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.dateChecked) + padding )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a xScale, but not used it with the dateCreated, and instead used an index.

Here's a working version of the code:

```js
let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

// function fired when state is selected
document.getElementById("state-select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
//   if there's already a chart, remove it
  let chart = document.getElementById("chart");
  if (chart) {
    chart.remove();
  };
  let state = e.target.value;
//   get state data
  fetch(`https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/${state}/daily.json`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
//     sort data by date, chop off initial null value
      data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
      data = data.slice(1);
//     turn data date strings into date objects
      data.forEach(item => {
        if (item.positiveIncrease < 0){
          item.positiveIncrease = 0
        }
        let dateObject = new Date(item.dateChecked);
        let year = dateObject.getFullYear();
        let month = dateObject.getMonth();
        let day = dateObject.getDate();
        item.dateChecked = new Date(year,month,day); //this is done this way to get rid of hour offsets/UTC
      });
      
    
//     set variables for dimensions and spacing
      const svgWidth = window.innerWidth * .8;
      const svgHeight = window.innerHeight * .8;
      const padding = 40;
      const chartWidth = svgWidth - padding;
      const chartHeight = svgHeight - padding*2;

      
//    build y scale
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear();
      yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, (d) => d.positiveIncrease),
      ]);
      yScale.range([chartHeight, 0]);
    
//     build y axis
      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);
    
//     build x scale
      const xScale = d3.scaleTime();
      xScale.domain([d3.min(data, d => d.dateChecked), d3.max(data, d => d.dateChecked)]);
      xScale.range([0, chartWidth]);
    
//     build x axis
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
      
//     add svg to svg wrapper
      const svg = d3
        .select("#svg-wrapper")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .attr('id', 'chart');
        
//      add axes
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, ${padding})`).call(yAxis);
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, ${chartHeight + padding })`).call(xAxis.ticks(d3.timeDay));

//     add bars
      const barSpace = 3;
      const barWidth = chartWidth / data.length - barSpace;
      let rect = svg
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("width", barWidth)
        .attr("height", (d) => yScale(0) - yScale(d.positiveIncrease))
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.dateChecked) + padding) //<-- This is the main change.
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.positiveIncrease) + padding);

//     add title to rects
      rect.append("title").text((d) => {return `${d.positiveIncrease}, ${months[d.dateChecked.getMonth()]} ${d.dateChecked.getDate()}`});
    
// //     add labels to rects
//     svg.selectAll('text')
//       .data(data)
//       .enter()
//       .append('text')
//       .attr('x', (d, i) => i * (barWidth + barSpace) + padding)
//       .attr('y', d => yScale(d.positiveIncrease) + padding - 20)
//       .text(d => d.positiveIncrease)
//       .style('font-size', '8px')

//     add header
      svg
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text(state + " New Cases Daily")
        .style("font-size", "1.5rem")
        .style("font-weight", "bold");
    });
});
```