# D3 version 6 - compute bar width for bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm using D3 version 6 to make a bar chart. But I'm hard coding the bar **width** and it's resulting in weird-looking bars that aren't evenly spaced:

[image]

My x scale is a time scale (`d3.scaleTime()`), used in my x axis:

```
const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

const x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .domain([parseTime('1930'),parseTime('2025')]);

const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

const group = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
group.append("g").call(xAxis);
```

Is there a way to set the bar width instead of a hard-coded **4**?

```
group.selectAll('bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "ref-count")
    .attr("y", d => y(d.count) )
    .attr("x", d => x(parseTime(d.year)) )
    .style("fill", color)
    .attr("width", 4)
    .attr("height", d => height - y(d.count));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need scaleTime? ScaleOrdinal and scaleBand are typically used for bars since they offer x.bandwidth() for the bar width

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use x and width in a bar chart with scaleTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278994/how-to-use-x-and-width-in-a-bar-chart-with-scaletime)