# How to set width for rect element in a bar chart using d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to plot a simple bar chart with date as x axis and temperature value as y axis. I'm using d3 library.

Created the xScale ans yScale as

```
const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
    .range([0, dimensions.boundWidth]);

const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yAccessor)])
    .range([dimensions.boundHeight, 0]);
```

Set the accessor functions as

```
const dateParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
const xAccessor = (d) => dateParse(d["date"]);
const yAccessor = (d) => d["temperatureMax"];
```

And drew the rectangles using

```
const barsGroup = bounds.append("g");
const barGroups = barsGroup
    .selectAll("mybars")
    .data(dataset.slice(0, 10))
    .join("g");

const barRects = barGroups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d) => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
    .attr("width", "10")
    .attr("height", (d) => dimensions.boundHeight - yScale(yAccessor(d)))
    .attr("fill", "darkgray");
```

I'm trying to find out how to set the `width` attribute. Here I set it as a constant "10" just to see something on screen. Also trying to find out how to set proper spacing between each bars. I have a set up a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/bar-chart-zfypoi?file=/index.js) with the above set up. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: You need to be careful when creating a bar chart with a time scale, have a look at my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279536/5768908